# get sendgrid dynamic template list

Tags: c#, .net, sendgrid

I am trying to get the new dynamic template(s) I have defined through the .net client but I only manage to retrieve the list of what they now call the "legacy" ones. Here is what I have (queryParams was just added but seems to be ignored) :

```
var test1 = @"{
    'generation': 'dynamic'
}";
var test2 = "{\"generation\": \"dynamic\"}";

var response = await _client
    .RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.GET, 
        urlPath: "templates", queryParams: test2);
var responseBody = await response.Body
        .ReadAsStringAsync();
var templateList = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeObject<SendGridTemplateList>(responseBody);
return templateList?
    .Templates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains(templateName))?
    .Versions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Active == 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I got confused somewhere, the correct way is to just edit the urlPath :

```
var response = await _client
    .RequestAsync(method: SendGridClient.Method.GET,
        urlPath: $"templates?generations=dynamic");
```